# approximating this sum by an integral

Tags: calculus, probability

I'm trying to understand a proof in Section 8.6 of Alon & Spencer's book The Probabilistic Method (Fourth Edition). It is based on an [old paper of Erdős](https://old.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1956-17.pdf), but both Alon & Spencer and Erdős seem to leave out important details.

We define a random subset of the natural numbers $S$ as follows. We say that
$$\mathbb{P}[ x \in S] = p_x = \min \left[ 10 \sqrt{\frac{\log x}{x}}, 1 \right]$$
for every natural number $x$.

Let $f(n)$ denote the number of ways to write $n$ as $n=x+y$ with $x,y \in S$.

By linearity of expectation, $f(n)$ is a random variable whose mean is given by
$$\mu = \mathbb{E} [f(n) ] =\frac{1}{2} \sum_{x+y=n, x\neq y} p_xp_y.$$

Then, Alon & Spencer write that "careful asymptotics (and first year calculus!) yield"
$$ \mu \approx 50 \log n \int_{0}^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}} dx = 50 \pi \log n.$$

But I'm stuck working out the details of why we can approximate the sum by this integral.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to avoid the part that requires careful asymptotics, and jump straight to the "sum approximately equals the integral" part. I'm also going to drop the $x \neq y$ condition on the sum, which I will claim can be done as part of the asymptotics. So we now just have:

$$\mu = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{x + y = n} p_x p_y$$

but notice that although there are two variables, this is actually a single summation, which we can re-index as:

$$\mu = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{x = 1}^{n - 1} p_x p_{n - x}$$

I'm going to do a little handwaving at this point (with argument to the asymptotics), and assume that $n$ is large enough that both $p_x$ and $p_{n-x}$ are *mostly* of the form $10 \sqrt{\frac{\log x}{x}}$, and I'm going to make that substitution along with a little bit of sneaky rearrangement:

$$\begin{eqnarray} \mu & \approx & \frac{1}{2} \sum_{x = 1}^{n - 1} 10 \sqrt{\frac{\log x}{x}} 10 \sqrt{\frac{\log (n - x)}{n - x}} \\
& = & \frac{1}{2} \sum_{x = 1}^{n - 1} 100 \sqrt{\frac{\log x \log(n - x)}{x(n - x)}} \\
& = & \frac{1}{2} \sum_{x = 1}^{n - 1} 100 \sqrt{\frac{\log (n \frac{x}{n}) \log (n (1 - \frac{x}{n}))}{n \frac{x}{n} n (1 - \frac{x}{n})}} \\
& = & \frac{100}{2} \sum_{x = 1}^{n - 1} \sqrt{\frac{(\log n + \log \frac{x}{n})(\log n + \log(1 - \frac{x}{n}))}{n^2 \frac{x}{n} (1 - \frac{x}{n})}} \\
& = & 50 \sum_{x = 1}^{n - 1} \frac{1}{n} \sqrt{\frac{(\log n)^2 + \log n (\log \frac{x}{n} + \log(1 - \frac{x}{n})) + \log \frac{x}{n} \log (1 - \frac{x}{n})}{\frac{x}{n}(1 - \frac{x}{n})}}
\end{eqnarray}$$

This is looking a little ugly, but again I'm going to defer to the asymptotics, and claim that the $(\log n)^2$ term dominates over the other two terms when $n$ is large enough. If that's the case, then this reduces to:

$$\mu \approx 50 \log n \sum_{x = 1}^{n - 1} \frac{1}{n} \sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{x}{n}(1 - \frac{x}{n})}}$$

The final step is to just notice that this is exactly a Riemann sum for the required integral.